# How to covert MappartitionsRDD[] to list or vector, then export as csv file?

Tags: apache-spark

I used some training data to build a Random Forests to predict the diabetes, now I want to use this model to predict a set of patient, the corresponding features are stored in a csv file. Below is my code:

```
val sc = new SparkContext("local[4]", "RandomForestsMultiplePredict")
//load the RandomForestModel from the file
val RFModel = RandomForestModel.load(sc, "RFModelPath")
//Transform the data in the file to RDD<Vector> format to predict
val data = sc.textFile("data/Diabetes_for_Test.csv")
val features = data.map(x => Vectors.dense(x.split(',').map(_.toDouble))).cache()
//predict the data
val result = RFModel.predict(features)
```

After I get the result, I wanted to convert the MappartitionsRDD[] data to a list or vector, in order to export the predict result to a new csv file. How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: `results.collect()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading  [the API document of MappartitionsRDD](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/rdd/MapPartitionsRDD.html), I get to know that there is a method can be use.

```
result.toLocalIterator.toList
```

From @zero323 's help, I found

```
result.collect().toList
```

also works well. Thanks.

Comment: Wont collect() call get all data to be dumped to driver node ? shouldnt first option perform better ?